# Can I create an XMLHttpRequest using a standard JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I would like to create a function which creates the structure of a desired XMLHttpRequest and outputs it as a variable that I can use. I have attempted this with the following code:

```
function prepareXMLHttpRequest(type) {
  var targetURL = 'http://localhost:3000/';

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(type, targetURL, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  //set any other options here
  return xhr;
}
```

My intention is to call that function with either GET or POST, and then send the result:

```
prepareXMLHttpRequest("GET").then(function(getRequest) {
    getRequest.send();
    // Do something here, for example console.log the output
  })

prepareXMLHttpRequest("POST").then(function(postRequest) {
    postRequest.send(outputString);
  })
```

When I try either of these statements, I receive the following error:

```
PrepareXMLHttpRequest(...).then is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not returning a `Promise`. Use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)...

Comment: Preparing an `XMLHttpRequest` is **not** an asynchronous process so there's no point trying to promise-ify it. You might as well just have `const getRequest = prepareXMLHttpRequest('GET')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is expecting the `XMLHttpRequest` to have a `then` property, but it does not. In order the result from your function to be thenable you need to return a promise like below

```js
function prepareXMLHttpRequest(type) {
  var targetURL = 'http://localhost:3000/';
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open(type, targetURL, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
      event.readyState == 4 && event.status == 200 ? resolve(event) : reject(event)
    });
    xhr.send();
  })
}
```

**Edit:** the snippet above is just for illustration purposes for a good implementation that uses XMLHttpRequest() and returns Promise take a look at [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch)

Comment: Will that reject the promise before it is complete i.e. `readyState` is not 4?

Comment: @phuzi yes, my idea was not to show a good implementation. just a simple exampl e with promise

Comment: Fair enough, but I can see OP asking another question why the promise never gets resolved.

Comment: Personally, I'd use `onload` and `onerror` to trigger `resolve` and `reject` respectively

Comment: @Phil personally I'd use one of the many good and open source libraries, but you can fell free to edit and add to my answer :D

Comment: @Teneff this is great. You also managed to solve another issue I was having; I didn't realise readyState existed and this was blocking me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use the `fetch` API. It's a more modern approach to XMLHttpRequest that uses promises by default.

```
fetch("https://myapi.com")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API